# Get maximum number of jobs allowed in SLURM cluster as a user

Tags: slurm

I am working on a SLURM-based cluster, and I'd like to know if there exists a command (or a configuration file to look at) I could run as a user to know the maximum number of jobs I am allowed to run simultaneously (I did not find it in the Slurm documentation). Is there such a command ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The resource limit you should look into is `MaxJobs`.

As explained in [the docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html), it can be set in several ways. Per user association, per account (group of users), per cluster. Also, set directly by asociation or via the quality of service (QOS).

You should first check which account(s) is(are) associated with your user, e.g. with `sacctmgr list user $USER`.

Then, you can check `MaxJobs` with `sacctmgr list associations`. Look at both your account (near the top of the list) and your user.

Finally, check the values set with the QOS with `sacctmgr show qos` (look for `MaxJobsPU` and `MaxJobsPA`, per user and per account IIRC).